# How to process socket.io events in their incoming order

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the following setup:

```
async MyFunction(param) {
    //... Do some computation
    await WriteToDB()
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('AnEvent', (param) => MyFunction(param))
})
```

When an event comes in, it calls an asynchronous function which does some computation and in the end write the result to a database with another asynchronous call.

If MyFunction doesn't have an asynchronous call to write the database in the end, for example

```
MyFunction(param) {
    //... Do some computation
}
```

then it is obviously that all events will be processed in their incoming order. The processing of the next event will only start after the processing of the previous one finishes. However, because of the asynchronous call to the database, I don't know if those incoming events will still be fully processed in order. I am afraid that the processing of the next event starts before the previous `await WriteToDB()` finishes. How do I change the code to fully processing them in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there's no guarantee that incoming events will be processed in the order.

To achieve what you are asking, you would need a "Message Queue" that will periodically check for new messages and process them one by one.

```js
const messageQueue = [];

// SocketIO adding Message to MessageQueue
const eventHandler = (message) => {
  messageQueue.push(message);
}

const messageHandler = () => {
  if (messageQueue.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const message = messageQueue.shift();

  // Handle Message

  // If successful, ask for next message
  return messageHandler();
}
```

Of course, my example is pretty naive, but I hope it will give you a general idea of how what you are asking is accomplished.

If you are finding yourself needing a more robust message queue, Look into RabbitMQ, BullMQ, Kafka

Comment: How do I call messageHandler? It looks like it needs to be called multiple times. It will return after finishing consuming all messages, so it needs to be called when new messages comes.

Comment: Your Socket IO message handler (the handler which received a message from socket io) only needs to push the message into the message queue, then, another component in your application (generally provided by the message queue) periodically checks for new messages in the queue (messageQueue array in the example) and if there's a new message, it will process it.

Comment: I highly suggest you look into how BullMQ, RabbitMQ, Kafka works, your answer, and all future questions are most likely answered in their documentations.